# Should I use the Oxford comma?

Tags: punctuation

Esperanto uses the comma in sentences like *Nun mi scias, kio estas amo*, where English would not use it. (Italian would not use a comma either.)

Does that mean I should use the Oxford comma by default? Translating the following sentence in Esperanto, should I put a comma before *kaj*?

> I like to eat bagels, waffles, and English muffins, but not in that order.

Is the Oxford comma optional, but used to make the sentence clearer? For example, in American English, I would write *To my parents, the Pope, and Mother Theresa* because *To my parents, the Pope and Mother Theresa* would have a different meaning.

Comment: I've read (I have no reference) that the punctuation in Esperanto (and commas in particular) is similar to the punctiuation of the Slavic languages. In those (my reference is Bulgarian, which I speak natively), you *don't* put a comma before *"and"* when listing things, and you always surround subclauses with a comma on both sides, which differs from English (and as it seems Italian too).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the *[Plena Manlibro de Esperanta Gramatiko](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/skribo/helposignoj.html)*

> Komo estas uzata ene de frazoj en lokoj, kie povas esti nature iom paŭzi, ekz. antaŭ subfrazo, kaj **anstataŭ** la vortoj *kaj* kaj *aŭ* en elnombrado de pluraj aferoj. Komo estas iafoje uzata anstataŭ punkto inter ĉeffrazoj, kiuj iel kunapartenas. Komo estas ankaŭ uzata antaŭ decimaloj en nombroj: 3,14 (= “tri komo unu kvar”, “tri kaj dek kvar centonoj”). [emfazo estas mia]

Translation:

> A comma is used inside sentences in places where it can be natural to somewhat pause, for example before a subclause, and **instead of** the words *kaj* and *aŭ* in listing of several things. A comma is sometimes used instead of a period between main sentences, which are in some way dependent on each other. A comma is also used before decimals in numbers: 3,14 (="three comma one four", "three and fourteen hundredths"). [emphasis is mine]

Note the word "anstataŭ" ("instead of"). A comma before a conjunction is not "instead of", thus we conclude that it is standard not to use the Oxford Comma. However, some Esperantists (including myself) do use it, and I have never seen a miscomprehension, or even a flamewar, result from such usage.

In summary, if you want to follow the PMEG, don't use the Oxford Comma. But if you do it's not a big deal.