# aŭ…aŭ, nek…nek, and kaj…kaj for more than two items

Tags: word-usage

It’s basic grammar that the duplicative *aŭ…aŭ,* *nek…nek,* and *kaj…kaj* forms change a simple “or”, “nor” or “and” into “either…or”, “neither…nor” and “both…and”, respectively. (There are [more *kombinitaj vortetoj*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kombinitaj_vortetoj/index.html), including *ĉu…ĉu,* *jen…jen,* and the non-duplicative *ju…des.*)

But that [section of the PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kombinitaj_vortetoj/index.html) doesn’t, as far as I can tell, address the question of a series of *three or more* alternates.

In some languages, this construction is productive into arbitrary lists (and can even be mixed, like

> **both the first and the second nor the third* 
> ↓
>   
>  *either both the first and also the second, or, not the third*

which would connote that the first and the second imply the third but the third can also occur independently.)

But in other languages—including English in formal register—it’s not permitted to chain these at all; one must switch from

> *either the red or the green*

to

> *one of: the red, the green, or the blue.*

My intuition is that Esperanto should allow chaining into *nek…nek…nek* and so on, but not mixtures like *kaj…nek…kaj.*

This gut feeling arises from the *ju…des* case, where one can say *ju pli…des pli* or *ju malpli…des pli* or *ju pli…des malpli* and so on. This is a case that:

- explicitly allows for per-item negation (the first, second, or both can have the *mal-* following it)
- semantically only allows two items
- and uses two different words rather than the same word twice.

It feels like the fact that these semantics go hand-in-hand with the only case that uses two different introducing conjunctions implicitly suggests that the other cases, with their duplication of introducing conjunctions, *should* allow for a chain.

---

So, my question is in three parts:

1. Am I right that these chains are allowed?
2. If yes to #1, can you mix conjunctions in a chain?
3. If yes to #1, can you replace the second through penultimate conjunctions with commas? (e.g., *kaj la ruĝa, la verda kaj la blua*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That section of PMEG specifically says for all repeated *kombinitaj vortetoj*, that they can be used *pluroble*. Such multiple times repeated words can have different meanings (e.g. repeated *ĉu* can indicate indifference instead of question).

Comment: The first sentence, _Iuj vortetoj aperas pare aŭ pluroble kun specialaj signifoj._ suggested to me that multiples had special meaning vs. pairs... I read, “pare (kun kutima signifo) aŭ pluroble kun specialaj signifoj”. So that was where I went wrong, I think...

Answer (score 3):

In [*La Tekstaro*](https://tekstaro.com/), a search for `\bnek\b.*\bnek\b.*\bnek\b` returns (as its very first result!), Zamenhof’s

> La vera stilo Esperanta estas **nek** slava, **nek** germana, **nek** romana, ĝi estas – aŭ almenaŭ devas esti – nur stilo simpla kaj logika.

*(“…neither Slavic, nor Germanic, nor Romance…”)*

so—this seems like pretty definitive confirmation!

—*Except,* in English, substituting “neither…nor…nor” for “none of” is more acceptable (according *Oxford American,* at least) than “either…or…or” for “one of” and “both…and…and” for “all of”. And there are other languages that allow chaining of some combining conjunctions and not others.

Yet *La Tekstaro* has examples of *kaj…kaj…kaj* (including from Zamenhof), and *aŭ…aŭ…aŭ,* as well as *nek…nek…nek*.

So I think

1. Chaining the same combinative conjunction is fine.
2. Mixing them, like *nek…aŭ…kaj,* is *not.*

   (A *La Tekstaro* search for `\baŭ\b[^.]*\bnek\b[^.]*\baŭ\b` turns up results, but I could only see ones where the *nek* is subordinate to the *aŭ…aŭ*, not in a chain with it.)

But as for #3: can you use commas for the intervening conjunctions?

[This question](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/632/should-i-use-the-oxford-comma) about using the Oxford comma in Esperanto links to [Section 1.2 of PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/skribo/helposignoj.html), which says

> Komo estas uzata … anstataŭ la vortoj *kaj* kaj *aŭ* en elnombrado de pluraj aferoj.

or,

> A comma is used… instead of the words *kaj* and *aŭ* in listing of several things.

This sounds like the answer is yes—at least specifically in the cases of *kaj* and *aŭ*, but that's just an implicature. This is hard to search *La Tekstaro* for (unless there's a cleverer way I haven't found!).

Comment: I've wondered this myself and I have seen the example you found: _**nek** slava **nek** germana **nek** romana_ (note, that I prefer not to use commas between). If nothing more it surely show a style, that can be considered acceptable, i.e. _jes_, you can chain more than two, but with repeating the same _kombinita vorteto_.

Comment: Incidentally, the “neither... nor... nor” being possibly more acceptable is framed by noting that in English, _nor_ can be used independently of _neither_, e.g., “He wanted not for food, nor for water, nor for shelter”. Of course, _and_ can be used independent of _both,_ so I don’t think it’s a great explanation!